# How to require SSL for web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have taken code from this [page](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api). Basically, i am trying to require SSL on all requests. Here is the code I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;


namespace Test
{
    public class RequireSSL : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
            {
                actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
                {
                    ReasonPhrase = "HTTPS Required"
                };
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is I have a blue scriggily line under OnAuthorization that says "No suitable method to override". Not sure how to fix this. Any ideas?

Comment: Try inheriting from AuthorizeAttribute: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an attribute RequireHttpsAttrobute you can use: RequireHttpsAttribute

Comment: This is probably the better way to handle it - no need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully at the example, it's deriving from `AuthorizationFilterAttribute`, not `ActionFilterAttribute`. If you change that in your example, then it compiles correctly.